# Benchmarking two methods lead to first result being inaccurate

Tags: java, algorithm, benchmarking

I'm trying to benchmark two different methods for the same problem in this main function. However, the first benchmark for the *second* method differs a lot from the other results.

Also there's a problem sometimes where the elapsed time, for the *second* method, equaled 0.0 ns, which is strange to me.

What is it that I'm missing?

Output

```
Iterative Method    -   Elapsed time (µs)
                27.151
                26.895
                21.773
                28.432
                26.127
==================================================
Formula method      -   Elapsed time (µs)
                5.123
                1.281
                0.512
                0.513
                0.512
```

Main code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int testSize = 5;

    System.out.println("Iterative Method\t-\tElapsed time (µs)");
    for (int i = 0; i < testSize; i++)
    {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        iterativeMethod();
        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + estimatedTime/1000f);
    }
    System.out.println("==================================================");
    System.out.println("Formula method\t\t-\tElapsed time (µs)");
    for (int i = 0; i < testSize; i++)
    {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int foo = SumDivisibleBy(3) + SumDivisibleBy(5) - SumDivisibleBy(15);
        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + estimatedTime/1000f);
    }
}
```

Comment: For measuring time use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Reason for it is that it takes too long time (in nanoseconds) for the computer to get a reliable value from it.

Comment: Do not write your own benchmarking harness.  Use something like JMH (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmh) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java compiler and the JVM are allowed to mess with your code in so many ways, that it is *very* difficult to get a micro-benchmark right. 
For example, loops may be removed, instances may not be allocated at all, statements may be reordered and locks elided, etc.

So I'm afraid that a simple benchmark like this one is totally irrelevant, and you should not take its results too seriously.

Unless you know how to print the generated assembly and see what really happens at runtime in your code, I suggest you rewrite the benchmark using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

JMH is a benchmarking framework officially provided by Oracle, and specifically designed to take care of the JVM oddities and ensure the right things is actually measured.

It is quite easy to use, and all major IDEs have some kind of support for it. You can find JMH tutorials and resources [here](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.fr/p/jmh-related-posts.html).